# Left joins, i need an explanation about a code

Tags: mysql, left-join

i am watching a tutorial. There is a code which i don't understand what is supposed to do.

```
$sql = 'SELECT p.*, 
      a.screen_name AS author_name, 
      c.name AS category_name
    FROM 
      posts p
      LEFT JOIN 
        admin_users a ON p.author_id = a.id
      LEFT JOIN 
        categories c ON p.category_id = c.id
    WHERE 
      p.id = ?';
```

I read about the left joins but i didn't understand them. Can somebody please explain me the code i shared. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It does the same that all left JOINs do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you have two tables.  One that stores the information about the programmers on your website, and the other table that keeps track of their online purchases.

PROGRAMMERS Table

```
+--------------------------------------------+
| ID | NAME     | AGE | ADDRESS   | SALARY   |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Desire   |  32 | 123 fake s|  3000.00 |
|  2 | Jamin    |  25 | 234 fake s|  2500.00 |
|  3 | Jon      |  23 | 567 fake s|  2000.00 |
|  4 | Bob      |  30 | 789 fake s|  1500.00 |
|  5 | OtherGuy |  31 | 890 fake s|  1000.00 |
|  6 | DudeMan  |  32 | 901 fake s|   500.00 |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

PURCHASES Table

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| ORDER_ID    | PROG_ID |    DATE    | PRICE  | 
+-------------+---------+---------------------|
|  1          | 1       |  1-1-2017  | 100    |
|  2          | 2       |  1-2-2017  | 200    |
|  3          | 6       |  1-3-2017  | 300    |
+---------------------------------------------|
```

You decide you need to make a new table to consolidate this information to a table that contains
certain columns you want.

For example, you figure it would be nice for shipping purposes to have a table 
that has the ID, the NAME, the PRICE, and the DATE columns.

Currently, the tables we have don't display all of that in a single table.

If we were to LEFT JOIN these tables, we would end up filling the desired columns 
with NULL values where there is no information to join.

```
SELECT ID, NAME, PRICE, DATE
    FROM PROGRAMMERS
    LEFT JOIN PURCHASES
    ON PROGRAMMERS.ID = PURCHASES.PROG_ID;
```

Notice that I'm selecting the columns I want from the starting table, then joining the right table
even though there might be missing information.

RESULTING TABLE

```
+-------------------------------------+
| ID | NAME     | PRICE   |   DATE    |
+----+----------+-----------------+---+
|  1 | Desire   | 100     | 1-1-2017  |
|  2 | Jamin    | 200     | 1-2-2017  |
|  3 | Jon      | NULL    |   NULL    |
|  4 | Bob      | NULL    |   NULL    |
|  5 | OtherGuy | NULL    |   NULL    |
|  6 | DudeMan  | 300     | 1-3-2017  |
+-------------------------------------+
```

For a visual representation of the difference between SQL JOINs check out
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins .

Comment: Thanks mate. Now i understand it. I just have one more simple question. Can you tell me why do we SELECT p.* in the code i showed earlier? I understand that ".*" will match each word that starts with the letter "p". But i can't understand the purpouse of that.

Comment: @DesireOn Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3639964/7813290 about using " * ".  In this case it seems you are getting every column in p.

Comment: Thank you once again for saving me!! <3